# С чем согласовать чудотворность?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

> Большое количество мастеров – монастырских монахов, по примеру святого
>   Луки, начинают изготовлять **изображения** святых, **часть** которых
>   **считалась чудотворной**.

Почему мне не нравится падеж чудотворной части?

Comment: Единственное число не нравится: "чудотворная часть изображений святых". Некоторые или многие из которых.

Comment: Изготовлять изображения? И кто только изготовляет эти рукописи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большое количество мастеров – монастырских монахов, по примеру святого Луки, начинают изготовлять изображения святых, **причем некоторые из них считались чудотворными (были причислены к чудотворным).**

Answer (score 1):

1. Большое количество мастеров – монастырских монахов, по примеру святого Луки, начинают изготовлять изображения святых; некоторые иконы (из созданных икон) считались чудотворными.
2. Большое количество мастеров – монастырских монахов, по примеру святого Луки, начинают изготовлять изображения святых, и некоторые иконы прославятся как чудотворные.
3. Большое количество мастеров – монастырских монахов, по примеру святого Луки, начинают изготовлять изображения святых и создают ряд чудотворных икон.

Comment: «Создать чудотворную икону» — нонсенс. Икона после её создания живёт своей жизнью и может стать чудотворной.

Comment: @shampar Из самого предложения понятно, что имеется в виду создание ряда икон, которые проявили со временем свою чудотворную природу. Ведь мы говорим и пишем, например: «Пушкин создает свой гениальный призыв к свободе и воплощает его в стихотворении “Узник”; или: «В эти же самые годы Пушкин создает свои вершинные произведения».

Comment: Как нечто — чудо творящее — может «изготовить» человек? Его предел возможностей — «свои вершинные произведения».

Comment: @shampar Может, как и «вершинные произведения», которые признаются таковыми потомками. Кстати, чудотворные образы создаются и по заказу, и по специальной «технологии»: http://www.mepar.ru/library/vedomosti/67/1380/. Вопросы иконографии мне очень интересны, но, думается, обсуждать их стоит на другой площадке.

Comment: Значение слов — проблема не иконописания, там, будьте уверены, всё в порядке: образа пишут, и много. Так разве ж стоящие на полке во многих домах иконы, к примеру, св. Серафима Саровского чудотворные? Чудо конкретной из них (для начала) проявиться должно, а потом уж и признаваться. А у Вас иконы изначально «рядами создаются» .

Comment: @shampar Во-первых, я употребила слово «ряд» в единственном числе, а во-вторых, со значением слов в «настоящем историческом» все в порядке. Повторять аргументы не вижу смысла. Никого не хотела задеть или обидеть на этом сайте. Видимо, иметь мнение, отличное от вашего, не положено. В это Воскресенье прошу великодушно простить мою неуступчивость в споре.

Comment: Спора не было. Бог простит; и меня простите. С Великим постом Вас.

Comment: @shampar Бог простит, и я прощаю.